# What options does wget --report-speed take?

Tags: wget, download, byte

When I do this command:

```
wget --report-speed=type
```

they only *type* it accepts is `bits`. It won't have numbers, kilobits / kilobytes or bytes.

The help page (`wget --help`) says:

```
--report-speed=TYPE   Output bandwidth as TYPE.  TYPE can be bits.
```

suggesting that they TYPE **can** be something else?

What options does it take that I haven't found, and (if this option doesn't do this) how can I force the speed to be displayed as bytes or Kilobytes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a rather new addition to `wget` (1.13.4 doesn't have it) and there is no other value for that option, the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Logging-and-Input-File-Options.html#Logging-and-Input-File-Options) is quite clear:

```
‘--report-speed=type’

    Output bandwidth as type. The only accepted value is ‘bits’.
```

Comment: Ahh the help page just said *type* **can** be `bits`, making it sound like there were more...

Comment: I think they put this in expecting more types in future releases (maybe it is time to make feature request at the mailing list ;-) ).

Comment: Yes that would be nice - I'm grepping the speed and want to always be guaranteed that the speed I will get is KB/s so I can graph it...

Comment: This at least is what most ISPs use bits...it should default to this.

Answer (score 8):

Actually wget reports speed by default, and it would be in kilobytes/megabytes:

```
2017-07-08 23:33:45 (362 KB/s) - ‘openwrt-ar71xx-mikrotik-vmlinux-lzma.elf.4’ saved [1230693/1230693]
```

In case you would set an option '--report-speed=bits' it would report speed in megabits/kilobits, like

```
2017-07-08 23:33:21 (2.74 Mb/s) - ‘openwrt-ar71xx-mikrotik-vmlinux-lzma.elf.2’ saved [1230693/1230693]
```